# Why does the graph of the absolute error vs x for the three-point central difference formula have this shape?

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error, truncation-error

Using the three-point central difference formula,
$$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$
to approximate the $f'(x)$ of $f(x)= e^{-x} sin(x)$ for the interval $[0,15]$ using different step sizes ($h$) produces the following error vs $x$ [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUX9T.png).

I wanted to ask why there are these uniform 'bumps' in the error? where it dips all of a sudden for certain values of $x$. I've found lots of explanations going over plots of error vs $h$ but so far I haven't found anything for error vs $x$ graphs.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the rounding or truncation error suddenly decreasing? If so why at these $x$ points in particular?

Here's the python code for the $h=0.01$ line:

```
h = 0.01 # step size (h)
x = np.arange(0, 15, h)
g = np.exp(-x) * np.sin(x) # function f(x)

# find solutions to f'(x)
fn = (g[2:] - g[:-2]) / (2*h) # numerical solution
fa = np.cos(x) * np.exp(-x) - np.sin(x) * np.exp(-x) # analytical solution
err = np.abs(fa[1:-1] - fn)

plt.semilogy(x[1:-1], err, '.-')
```

Comment: In my opinion a better approach is to take some fixed value of $x$, and then to plot the absolute error as a function of $h$. This way you should get een parabolic shape.

Comment: @M.Wind I've done that already in other graphs this is more of a food for thought question that I was asked as part of a task

Comment: Mathematically there is no reason for strange bumps in the absolute error as a function of $x$. So numerical errors are presumably the cause.

Comment: To be clear, you are subtracting the central difference approximation for the derivative from the actual derivative and taking the absolute value? I have tried this but don't see the same error curve that you do.

Comment: @MartinVaughan yes, I didn't mention before but I plotted it with log scaling on the y-axis. I edited the post to add the code I used the plot the graphs

Comment: The _"three-point central difference formula"_ you show is called **Another two-point formula** in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Finite_differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method error in its leading term is for the central difference quotient
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=f'(x)+\frac{h^2}{6}f'''(x)+O(h^4)
$$
In the given case we get
$$
f(x)=e^{-x}\sin x\\
f'(x)=e^{-x}(\cos x-\sin x)\\
f''(x)=-2e^{-x}\cos x\\
f'''(x)=2e^{-x}(\sin x+\cos x)=2^{3/2}e^{-x}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi4\right)
$$
The error term will oscillate, changing sign. Close to its roots the error will be especially small. And indeed the dips in the graph are at about $\frac{3\pi}4\approx2\frac14$, $\frac{7\pi}{4}\approx 5\frac12$, $\frac{11\pi}{4}\approx8\frac12$, ...

The depth of the dips mainly depends on the sampling density, how close the samples get to the root of the error term.

Other sources of error contributions only become substantial at much smaller step sizes, down from $h=10^{-5}$ for the given situation.

Comment: You are plotting the graph of the derivative, not the one of the difference between derivative and difference quotient

Comment: I see so because the absolute error of the method is partly made of the $f'''(x)$ term and partly made of other additional terms (other error sources), it's inclined to go to zero at the same $x$ points where $f'''(x)$ goes to zero (hence the dips), but doesn't quite reach it because of the additional error terms & how close x is to the roots

Comment: thank you once again!

Comment: @m-stgt : Yes, your first plot (currently) shows the error, let's name it $e(x)$. The other graphs of it show $|e(x)|$ on a logarithmic scale. The left side of your graph looks consistent with the logarithmic plot, the right side is too small to see this.

Comment: @trxxns : No, as I said that is just simply the sampling rate. To get very low values in the abs-log plot, you need to hit the roots of the error very closely. The roots are not on the grid of the sampling points, there will be always a distance. That goes into the region of number theory and how good algebraic and transcendental numbers can be approximated by rationals. While the error term has size $10^{-4}$, the other contributions are as small as $10^{-13}$, thus can not be seen in the plot.

Comment: @LutzLehmann -- My bad, I overlooked the log scaled ordinate in OP, sorry. Updated my "temporary answer".