# why can the result of the four point finite difference formula of a function, be greater than the exact derivative of the function?

Tags: derivatives, finite-differences

if i have a function like $f(x) = e^{\sqrt{x+\frac{2}{x}}}$.

why is the result of using the formula below, where $x$ is $2$ and $h$ is $0.1$, greater than the exact derivative of $f(x)$?

[image]

Comment: Given that there are 2 $+$ and 2 $-$ signs in the formula. *Why not?*

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile you probably found an answer to your questions on your own. Nonetheless I took the time to take a closer look. I turns out that the result of your four point finite difference **approximation** formula is just $0.0025$% biger than $f'(2)$. In case this deviation is too much I'd suggest you reach for another approximation.

Notwithstanding this nothingness of $0.0025$% this does not answer the reason of the **positive** deviation. Maybe you plotted a graph of your function, at $x=2$ it is *convex*. Even so your four point approximation formula is *symetric* the higher slope at $x=2.1$ and $x=2.2$ is reflected in the result.

There is [an explanation for a simpler numeric derivative approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877954/why-does-the-graph-of-the-absolute-error-vs-x-for-the-three-point-central-differ/4878305#4878305) showing "funny" results when the function changes from concave to convex and back. It could also help to shed some light on your observation.